# How to match a query's response to its parent query?

Tags: query, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query-task

Using ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.24 I'm triggering a series of queries, then sending the responses to a function to handle them. Here is a simplified example:

```
let whereClauses = ["capital = 'Y'", "capital = 'N'", "pop2000 < 0", "pop2000 > 100000"];
whereClauses.forEach(whereClause => {
  let query = new Query();
  query.where = whereClause;
  query.outFields = "*";
  citiesLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(handleQueryResponse)
})
  
function handleQueryResponse(results){
  console.log("Which query created these features?", results.features)
}
```

Within the `handleQueryResponse` function, how can I tell which `queryFeatures` operation was the source of the response (ie, what was the `where` clause used)? The `results` object doesn't seem to contain any means of identifying the parent query.

When there are `results.features` returned, each feature has a `layer` property pointing to the parent layer, but in my example all queries are triggered from the same layer, with different `where` clauses. Furthermore, the 3rd query doesn't return any features so there's not even a means of tying it to the parent layer. Note also the because the queries are asynchronous there's no guarantee that the first query leads to the first set of results.

Is it possible to pass an additional parameter along with the query, so that the query results can be tied back to the query?

Example code is at https://codepen.io/slead/pen/YzLvYGx - see the developer tools console for the query responses.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that I need to use `async/await` in order to return the results within the same scope, to give me access to the calling query:

```
let whereClauses = ["capital = 'Y'", "capital = 'N'", "pop2000 < 0", "pop2000 > 100000"];
whereClauses.forEach(whereClause => {
  let query = new Query();
  query.where = whereClause;
  query.outFields = "*";
  runQuery(citiesLayer, query, whereClause)
})
  
async function runQuery(layer, query, whereClause){
  let results = await layer.queryFeatures(query)
  handleQueryResponse(results, whereClause)
}
  
function handleQueryResponse(results, whereClause){
  console.log("Got results", results.features, "from query", whereClause)
}
```

[image]